# Stumped on solving a recurrence equation

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, recurrence

Here is the equation I'm working with (it's from a past exam question that I got wrong):

```
void foo(float[] array, int start, int end){
    if((end-start) <= 1) return;

    int x = (end-start) / 5;
    int y = 2*x;
    int z = 4*x;

    foo(array,start,start+y);
    for(index = y; index <z; index++){
            array[index]++;
    }
    foo(array,start+z,end);
}
```

How would I go about coming up with a recurrence equation for this?
I'm not sure of the notation I should use since the function #recurrences is depending on the value of end-start...

T(1) = 1 
T(N) = ***_*___** + **__*_*_** + ***_*____**

Answer (score 1):

```
for notation simplicity, lets call N = end-start
then:
 foo(array,start,start+y);  // T(2/5 * N)
 for(index = y; index <z; index++)  // 2/5 * N
 foo(array,start+z,end);  // T(N/5)

T(N) = T(2/5 * N) + 2/5 * N + T(N/5)
```

is that close enough?

Comment: I guess the first part should be `T(N/5)` instead. Otherwise, it's great. It's true that you should denote `end-start` as `N`. =D